# "It has it's reason …"

Tags: punctuation, apostrophe, contractions

Is this grammatically correct?

> It has it’s reason why it has to be happened”.

Tried to check it on Google but its not there. I just need to clarify if this statement is correct for the quotation that Im constructing.

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence has the following errors:

1. The contraction “it’s” is *always* a contraction for “it is”; your usage here is the third-person singular neuter possessive, which should *always* be “its”, without the apostrophe.
2. The construction “has to be happened” is not correct. You should use “happened”, or “has to have happened”, depending on context (which you do not provide enough of to determine which would be better).

“It has its reason why it happened.” would be acceptable from someone with limited English proficiency; more idiomatic would be “It has its reasons for happening.”